# How to know number of Request Units (RUs) consumed using azure-cosmosdb-spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

How to know number of Request Units (RUs) consumed using "azure-cosmosdb-spark" SDK ?

And is it possible to restrict not to cross provisioned RUs while reading?

When querying Azure Cosmos from databricks using "azure-cosmosdb-spark" SDK
It is crossing provisioned RUs on Cosmos.

How to restrict load(), not to cross provisioned RUs

I didn't find config to do from documentation

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/wiki/Configuration-references

```
READ_COSMOS_SPARK_CONN = {
  "Endpoint" : "---",
  "Masterkey" : --,
  "Database" : "--",
  "Collection" : "--",
}
 
READ_COSMOS_SPARK_CONFIG = {
  **READ_COSMOS_SPARK_CONN,
  "query_pagesize" : "2147483647",
  "SamplingRatio" : "1.0",
  "schema_samplesize" : "10",
}

df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**READ_COSMOS_SPARK_CONFIG).load()


dfResult = (
  df  
  .filter(sf.col('timestamp') >= "2021-02-21T00:00:00")
  .filter(sf.col('timestamp') < "2021-02-22T00:00:00")
 )

display(dfResult)
```

**Note**:
I used "query_custom" but no use. It actually increased my RUs consumptions.

and I can't query on partition key for complex reasons.

But I applied index on "timestamp".

Comment: Given that the Spark connector really has no way to know what specific reads or queries will cost, there's no way to tell it how much or how little to read. However: Cosmos DB will throttle when the RU/sec allotment has been exhausted - you can't really exceed RU allocation (aside from an operation allowed to complete, but then Cosmos DB throttles until the "RU debt" is paid off over the next few milliseconds).

Comment: Ok, If I reduce "query_pagesize" to lower number. Will it reduce throttle?